# Kinect Tilt upwards setting

Tags: kinect

I just got a Kinect and I have it connected to the computer using the USB. However, I don't know how to make the kinect tilt upwards so it is not looking downwards at the desk.

The question becomes. Is there a program to control such settings?
I have installed Microsoft Kinect 1.0 Beta 2 SDK.

Comment: The application called Camera Tilt is there for this'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some good tutorials on **kinect motor** :

http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectSDKQuickstarts/Camera-Fundamentals

http://cm-bloggers.blogspot.com/2011/06/kinect-sdk-camera-tilt.html

More **Resources to Start** with kinect sdk :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2011/06/13/unleash-the-power-of-kinect-for-windows-sdk.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/kinectsdknuiapi/thread/5e8c4bc0-3a5d-4309-8d95-d92199c208e0/

http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/

http://www.freenect.com/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/sdk-kinect-demo

Answer (score 0):

I made this using Visual Studio Express and the Kinect SDK
http://tekk-support.com/dev/kinect/kinect_motor_control.exe

If someone can upload this somewhere permanent, that would be nice

"You should tilt the Kinect as few times as possible, to minimize wear on the sensor and to minimize tilting time. The tilt motor is not designed for constant or repetitive movement, and attempts to use it that way can cause degradation of motor function. To reduce wear, your application should change the elevation angle no more than once per second. In addition, you must allow at least 20 seconds of rest after 15 consecutive changes. If your application exceeds these limits, the tilt motor may experience a lock period during which attempting to set the elevation angle will result in an error code." 
-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.kinectsensor.elevationangle.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the app at: http://kinecttiltcontrol.codeplex.com/

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer.